# Android things Pico Pro Maker Kit: How can I install Ubuntu server?

Tags: server, android, 20.04, raspberrypi, webserver

I have Android Things Pico Pro Maker Kit (NXP i.MX7D Starter Kit) (Refer: [Get started with Android Things kits](https://developer.android.com/things/get-started/kits)).

How can I install ubuntu server on it?